# How to derive parametric instances from general class to a more specialized (or just slighly different) class?

Tags: haskell

I'm getting the following error when trying to use an API I've been working on:

```
/home/bebarker/workspace/DouglasMetabolicModels/src/COBRA/MATLAB/Engine/Util.hs:14:9: warning: [-Wsimplifiable-class-constraints]
    • The constraint ‘MXArrayComponent a’
        matches an instance declaration
      instance Foreign.Matlab.Array.MXArrayComponent a =>
               MXArrayComponent a
        -- Defined in ‘Foreign.Matlab.ZIOArray’
      This makes type inference for inner bindings fragile;
        either use MonoLocalBinds, or simplify it using the instance
    • In the type signature:
        disp :: (HasEngine r, MXArrayComponent a) =>
                MXArray a -> ZIO r MatlabException ()
```

This occurs in the function definition:

```
disp :: (HasEngine r, MXArrayComponent a) => MXArray a -> ZIO r MatlabException ()
disp arr = engineEvalFun "disp" [EvalArray arr] 0 <&> discard
```

The base class looks like this in `Array.hs`:

```
-- |The class of standardly typeable array elements
class MXArrayComponent a where
  -- |Determine whether the given array is of the correct type
  isMXArray :: MXArray a -> MIO Bool
  ... more stuff
```

And an instance in that same module looks like:

```
-- |Complex array access.
instance (RealFloat a, MNumeric a, MXArrayData mx a) => MXArrayComponent (MComplex a) where
  isMXArray = isMXArrayMComplex
  createMXArray = createMXArrayMComplex
  mxArrayGetOffset = mxArrayGetOffsetMComplex
  mxArraySetOffset = mxArraySetOffsetMComplex
  mxArrayGetOffsetList = mxArrayGetOffsetListMComplex
  mxArraySetOffsetList = mxArraySetOffsetListMComplex
```

Then in a different module (`ZIOArray.hs`) I've got a similar class that uses `ZIO` instead of `IO` in some cases:

```
-- |The class of standardly typeable array elements
class MXArrayComponent a where
  -- |Determine whether the given array is of the correct type
  isMXArray :: MXArray a -> ZIO r MatlabException Bool
  ... more stuff
```

In this case, I auto-derive all instances parametrically:

```
instance A.MXArrayComponent a => MXArrayComponent a where
  isMXArray = ezlift . EA.isMXArray
  createMXArray = ezlift . EA.createMXArray
  createMXScalar = ezlift . EA.createMXScalar
  isMXScalar = ezlift . EA.isMXScalar
  mxScalarGet = ezlift . EA.mxScalarGet
  createRowVector = ezlift . EA.createRowVector
  mxArrayGetOffset a o = ezlift $ EA.mxArrayGetOffset a o
  mxArraySetOffset a o mcv = ezlift $ EA.mxArraySetOffset a o mcv
  mxArrayGetOffsetList a o n = ezlift $ EA.mxArrayGetOffsetList a o n
  mxArraySetOffsetList a o v = ezlift $ EA.mxArraySetOffsetList a o v
```

What is the best way to handle this situation? It seems that requiring users to have to use `MonoLocalBinds` just for this would not be ideal.

I'm fortunate that I'm writing the library so that gives me some flexibility in determining how to move forward, though if there is also a non-intrusive way to handle this on the API-user's side, that might be good to know for future reference as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the instance:

```
import qualified Foreign.Matlab.Array as A
instance A.MXArrayComponent a => MXArrayComponent a
```

it looks like your local `MXArrayComponent` class is redundant.  The class of types it describes are precisely those described by the existing class `A.MXArrayComponent`.  It's only purpose is to serve as a container for type signatures (the `class`) and implementations (the single `instance`), but you don't need or want a class for that.

So, delete your `class MXArrayComponent`, re-export the base class `A.MXArrayComponent` instead, and write the "methods" at top-level with a constraint using re-exported base class:

```
module ZIOArray 
  (..., A.MXArrayComponent, ...)
  where

import qualified Foreign.Matlab.Array as A

isMXArray :: A.MXArrayComponent a => MXArray a -> ZIO r MatlabException Bool
isMXArray = ezlift . A.isMXArray

-- etc.
```